# Desk wall mount

Tags: mounting

I want to install a wall mounted desk in our living room. The goal is to only mount it on the left and back wall (see image).

The table is glulam beech (200cm x 60cm x 3cm).

[image: Where the desk will be mounted]

Option 1:

I wonder if just doweling a square piece to the bottom back and left that then is mounted to the wall would be strong enough? (dry wood wall, mounted to beams)

[image: Construction under desk that's mounted to the wall]

Option 2:

I was thinking about adding supports below, but not sure if that's necessary or would help much.

[image: Construction under desk with additional support]

Option 3:

Maybe there is a better/stronger way to mount the desk I've not considered yet?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. You can certainly mount a surface this way (although a 2m extension is really pushing it), but of course it would be much stronger and more stable if you put in a support of some kind to the right. The ideal is a leg of some kind that extends to the floor (it doesn't have to be right out at the corner), but a diagonal brace up from the back wall is definitely better than nothing.

Comment: This is a judgement call and not everyone would agree, but in a busy space like a living room the only way I would trust this without a leg or diagonal bracing is if it were installed like a gigantic floating shelf, with metal supports that extend deeply both the wall and the panel. Your option 2 could add sufficient support, **if** implemented strongly enough; the main issue being how strongly it/they are attached to the wall because of the amount of potential leverage — you've got to plan for someone to perch themselves on the edge with their full weight (intentionally or otherwise).

Comment: @Graphus thanks for the comment. Yeah, 2 meters is really pushing it. I really try not to have a leg on the front right.

Making the suggested support higher would probably help as it would reduce the lever if mounted on the top and bottom. Not sure what that would look like tho. I might be better off getting some metal supports as you suggested (metal `◸` piece).

Comment: A diagonal bracket extending back to the wall near the floor would work well and would be less visible from the front.  The bracket/brace does not have to be solid (minimum 1.5 x 1.5 profile should work), but the wall must be braced at the point of contact.  Assuming that this is a stud framed wall, you can be sure to connect to solid framing in the wall if the brace connects to the wall at the floor.  Stud walls always have a continuous 2x4 bottom plate at the floor line.